# What is db viewer for Berkeyley DB and LevelDB?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Wallet uses Berkeyley DB. Block and transaction use LevelDB to index.
In bitcoin data we see the db data folder. 
Is there some tool to view these DB data ? I mean the database management tool.

Comment: leveldb is a key value store. there’s little about it that is human readable.

Comment: You can use [`db-util`](https://askubuntu.com/a/452072/790482) to view BerkeleyDB contents.